# Highlight answerer's name in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

[image: Comment screenshot]

In the first comment in the above image, Chris's username is highlighted, because he is the original question asker. Sam's comment however, looks like anyone else's, despite being the answerer. While in the case of this particular comment chain, it doesn't really matter who is replying to Chris, in others, especially longish chains, it can get confusing who is the asker, answerer, and chimer-inners. Perhaps something minor, such as underlining it?

Comment: @mhlester It was also four years ago, and while in general I agree that dupes are bad (and I don't know how I feel about this particular feature request) I think SE has changed so much in the last 4 years that most things are fair to be discussed again. (I agree with you, just expanding on the point :))

Comment: Dupe is a dupe, we can bump that older request and ask the team to reconsider. (@mhlester FYI as well)

Comment: Yeah yeah, but status-declined is a bit of a death knell...

Comment: Besides, @Shadow, I think I get a bit of a free pass considering I couldn't close if I wanted to. All I can do is flag.

Comment: @mhlester not really a death knell. Saw more than once declined request getting done eventually. Jeff had nasty habbit of declining things on his own without ever explaining. Now the team has grown and many things can be reconsidered, this might be one of them. I'm quite "meh" about it personally but one who care enough can start a bounty to revive that old request.

Comment: @ShadowWizard how would i bump the request?

Comment: @Scimonster bounty is the best option, if you're short on rep you can edit or even add a new answer where you suggest your idea and mockup of how it should look like. All of those will bump the question back to front and give it another chance.